# How to find one hamiltonian path in cube((2n)^3)?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I solve acm-icpc problem a kind of graph theory.

> Traveling Spiders is a logical puzzle that needs a sequence of
>   systematic choices among many alternatives. The puzzle assumes a
>   geometric object whose surface is partitioned into a set of areas
>   called cells that are usually congruent, or very similar in their
>   shapes and sizes. A spider may move around freely on the surface of
>   the object, but, can move forward from a cell to only one of its
>   neighboring cells in each step. Now, given some pairs of male and
>   female spiders, initially positioned all in different cells, we want
>   to find a set of paths that, respectively, leads each male spider to
>   his partner. The only condition is that every cell of the object must
>   be visited once and only once by a male spider during their traversal.

the cube exists in the space [0, 2n] x [0, 2n] x [0, 2n], and n can be 2 <= n <= 50.

we have to find one hamiltonian path when I game two position start from A to B.

and print all of path(1 0 1 -> 1 0 3 -> .... -> 3 1 4).

My friend said it is can't see general answer. because It is quite difficult to exact planar graph. and It cannot judge hamiltonian path or not.

how I can find hamiltonian path in general case?;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) problem, specifically [n-ary Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Special_types_of_Gray_codes).

Gray codes are Hamiltonian cycles, but you are looking for a Hamiltonian path with end vertices A and B. I'm not sure, but maybe [Monotonic Gray codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Special_types_of_Gray_codes) can help. If cube vertices can be partitioned in `V_i`, so that `V_0 = {A}, V_n = {B}`, than construction in article can solve problem.

**Edit:** There is a reference, on Wikipedia page, to Knuth's draft of [n-tuple generation](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc2a.ps.gz) from The Art Volume 4A.

Comment: @David: It is by construction. H_n is union of 0 + H_{n-1} and 1 + inverse H_{n-1}.

Comment: But the union is also true for the other 5 gray codes in a rubic cube i.e. octree. Isn't this just a recursive function? Why is a gray code a hamiltonian cycle?

Comment: Original Gray code asked only for reflected code property (only one change). It is also Hamiltonian cycle by construction (easy to prove with induction). Other definitions and constructions, as I can recall, ask for Hamiltonian cycle property.

Comment: Thus cyclic isn't recursive? What's the difference?

Comment: Cycle means that first and last vertex in a path are same. What do you mean with recursive?

Comment: Nothing, but I had really trouble to find a hamiltonian path with the fleury algorithm. Could it help to solve the task of a rubic cube?

Comment: Fleury's algorithm is for finding Eulerian paths and cycles, not Hamiltonian.

Comment: From Wikipedia: Eulerian cycle is a Eulerian trail which starts and ends on the same vertex.

Comment: Eulerian path visits every edge exactly once, while Hamiltonian path visits each vertex exactly once. Similar definitions, but very different topics :-)

Comment: I know what is a vertex and what is an edge and I know what is a gray code and what is a hamiltonian path but I'm confused now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269013/difference-between-hamiltonian-path-and-euler-path

Answer (score 1):

The problem is NP complete and you need to brute force every possible path. See here: [Algorithms to find the number of Hamiltonian paths in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333161/algorithms-to-find-the-number-of-hamiltonian-paths-in-a-graph). However, in your task there is a shortcut because it's a rubic cube and a gray code traversal of a rubics cube is a hamiltonian path. There are 6 ways of a gray code traversal of a rubic cube. For example if you have an octree and you find a hamiltonian path most likely you have found a space-filling-curve reducing the 3d to a 1d complexity. Then you can sort the path from top to bottom or from bottom to top. When you have the other 5 space-filling-curves you can have other lists. Here is a link that explains the difference between an euler path and a hamiltonian path: [Difference between hamiltonian path and euler path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269013/difference-between-hamiltonian-path-and-euler-path). Here is an example of a hilbert curve http://www.tiac.net/~sw/2008/10/Hilbert/ and it uses a binary-reflected code, not a n-ary code or a monotonic gray code.

Comment: I don't think he wants all paths, just one.  "print all of path" -- I understand this as "print all the steps in the path you found".